# My output is not displaying correctly did I call my definitions correctly, and did I return the values of those definitions correctly?

Tags: python

I have a couple of questions for my code. I want it to post the the highest and lowest value with lists of dates and price. right now it is not posting the columns, I tried calling my definition as final_list and implement in the print statement when posting columns requested. it returned "None" in the output. It did not work. So Now I'm wondering if my definitions returns the correct values.

1. did I return the correct values in my definitions
2. did I call the definitions correctly for the columns to show up in my output?
3. What do I have to implement in my print statement for "lowest" and
   "highest" for the columns to show, if I don't have a variable to
   implement. Ignore this but kindly let me know so I can fix it.

What my output currently is:

```
Enter a file name: table.csv
Which column: 5
Lowest 5:
Highest 5:
do you want to continue?
```

What I want my output to be:

```
Which column: 6
Lowest 6 for column 6
Date:08-1985, Value: 1.70
Date:09-1985, Value: 1.77
Date:06-1985, Value: 1.84
Date:10-1985, Value: 1.90
Date:07-1985, Value: 1.93
Date:11-1985, Value: 2.19
Highest 6 for column 6
Date:09-2012, Value:674.54
Date:08-2012, Value:635.39
Date:10-2012, Value:628.17
Date:04-2012, Value:597.19
Date:07-2012, Value:592.33
Date:03-2012, Value:569.11
```

```
# Project No.: 5
# Author: 
# Description: making definitions, reading from a .csv file, validating input, data-mining,

f_list = list()
file_object = ()
my_tot = dict()
new_list = list()

def get_input_descriptor():
    while True:
        filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
        if filename == 'table.csv':
            with open(filename, "r") as infile:
                infile.readlines()[1:]
                # for line in lines:
                #     print(line.rstrip())
                break
        else:
            print("Bad file name, try again")
    return file_object

def get_data_list(file_object, column_number):
    dict = {}
    for val in file_object:
        date = val.split(",")[0]
        data = float(val.split(",")[column_number])
        dict[date] = data
    return dict.items()

def average_data(new_list):
    for date, price in new_list:
        my_tot[date] = my_tot.get(date, 0) + float(price)
        my_times[date] = my_times.get(date, 0) + 1
    for key in my_tot:
        f_list.append((float(my_tot[key] / my_times[key]), key))


def main():
    get_input_descriptor()
    column_number = int(input("Which column: "))
    date_list = get_data_list(file_object, column_number)
    final_list = average_data(date_list)
    x = sorted(f_list)
    print('Lowest', str(column_number) + ":")
    for tup in x[:6]:
        print
        tup[0], tup[1]
    print('Highest', str(column_number) + ":")
    x = sorted(f_list, reverse=True)
    for tup in x[:6]:
        print
        tup[0], tup[1]

    while 1:
        flag = input("do you want to continue? ")
        if flag == '' or not flag[0].lower() in ['y', 'n']:
            print("Please answer with a yes or no")
        else:
            break
    if flag[0].lower() == 'y':
        column = input("Which column: ")
        print(column)

    if flag[0].lower() == 'n':
        print("Bye!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The csv.file Looks like this (first few lines, total of 1700 lines):

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2013-02-08,474,478.81,468.25,474.98,22597100,474.98
2013-02-07,463.25,470,454.12,468.22,25163600,468.22
2013-02-06,456.47,466.5,452.58,457.35,21203800,454.7
2013-02-05,444.05,459.74,442.22,457.84,20476700,455.19
2013-02-04,453.91,455.94,442,442.32,17039900,439.76
2013-02-01,459.11,459.48,448.35,453.62,19267300,450.99
2013-01-31,456.98,459.28,454.98,455.49,11404800,452.85
2013-01-30,457,462.6,454.5,456.83,14898400,454.18
2013-01-29,458.5,460.2,452.12,458.27,20398500,455.61
2013-01-28,437.83,453.21,435.86,449.83,28054200,447.22
2013-01-25,451.69,456.23,435,439.88,43143800,437.33
2013-01-24,460,465.73,450.25,450.5,52173300,447.89
2013-01-23,508.81,514.99,504.77,514.01,30768200,511.03
2013-01-22,504.56,507.88,496.63,504.77,16483800,501.85
2013-01-18,498.52,502.22,496.4,500,16890100,497.1
2013-01-17,510.31,510.75,502.03,502.68,16202800,499.77
2013-01-16,494.64,509.44,492.5,506.09,24671600,503.16
2013-01-15,498.3,498.99,483.38,485.92,31313300,483.1
2013-01-14,502.68,507.5,498.51,501.75,26221700,498.84
```

Thank you, hope this was detailed and concised.

Comment: The desired output is important, but you forgot to post the actual output ...

Comment: What is file_object that you are returning in def get_input_descriptor():? you have not defined it in that method, it will always be sent as empty file_object = ()

Comment: @Programmer, I described the actual output in my description... and what I tried implementing. however I will edit the question to be more specified.

Comment: @Neeraj Thank you for your input.

Comment: Please share a sample input and sample output as well if you are still getting nulls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: @EggCoder now its good

Comment: So in what columns are the "values" you wish to retrieve? Does that require some calculation? If not, you can probably adapt the script I posted in my second answer below to sort data from whatever columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

So your CSV file has six columns? What is the data in each of them and how would the person entering an integer know which ones are available?

You are obviously only interested in dates and values, disregarding data in other columns.

So what I would probably do is try to write this to a dictionary when reading the CSV file line by line to look like this:

```
dict = {
  "08-1985": "1.70",
  "06-1985": "1.77", 
  "09-1985": "1.84"
}
```

Then you can easily return six key-value pairs that either have the newest date, oldest date, largest value or smallest value?

If it is important to tell the user that the pair is "date: value", you can simply print the information before calling keys or values from the dictionary.

It seems to cause unnecessary complications to preserve the whole `"Date: 08-1985"` and `"Value: 1.70"` strings. I would split by delimiters ":" and "," when first reading the CSV data and only preserve the actual information you want to work with.

Comment: Edited in what the csv.file shows, there's not 6 columns rather I am requesting number 1 - 6 columns to be shown. Is your method of solving not hard-coding though? Rather than reading from the file. My bad for not understanding and not posting enough details. Didn't wanna post too much.

Comment: I think what you mean is rows than, not columns. You want to show six rows from two different columns, one being date, one values? And is "date: " / "value: " only the column header? That would make it a lot easier. If you could just share a few samples lines from the actual CSV file, we would better understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to the previous answer, here is a different approach, assuming that `"date: "` and `"value: "` are column headers and not part of the row data in the csv file:

```
# script for sorting nested lists
# adapted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-according-second-element-sublist/


import csv

mycsv="C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\mycsv.csv"

table=[row for row in csv.reader(open(mycsv)) if row]
print(table)
# output should look like this:
# [['08-1985', '1.70'], ['07-1966', '1.57'], ['01-1982', '1.89']]

# Sort first element in nested lists

def sortdate(nested):
    l = len(nested)
    for i in range(0, l):
        for j in range(0, l-i-1):
            if (nested[j][0] > nested[j + 1][0]):
                tempo = nested[j]
                nested[j]= nested[j + 1]
                nested[j + 1]= tempo
    return nested


# Sort second element in nested lists 

def sortvalue(nested):
    l = len(nested)
    for i in range(0, l):
        for j in range(0, l-i-1):
            if (nested[j][1] > nested[j + 1][1]):
                tempo = nested[j]
                nested[j]= nested[j + 1]
                nested[j + 1]= tempo
    return nested

# Print first six items in sorted lists

print(sortdate(table)[:6])
print(sortvalue(table)[:6])
```

My input file had 2 columns and 10 rows and looked like this:

```
01-1678, 1.34
03-1678, 1.54
02-1567, 1.92
10-1267, 1.89
11-1567, 1.90
12-1679, 1.06
03-1465, 1.78
04-1577, 1.38
05-1898, 1.22
06-1966, 1.66
```

Output I am getting for sorting by date is:

```
[['01-1678', ' 1.34'], ['02-1567', ' 1.92'], ['03-1465', ' 1.78'], ['03-1678', ' 1.54'], ['04-1577', ' 1.38'], ['05-1898', ' 1.22']]
```

Output for sorting by value is:

```
[['12-1679', ' 1.06'], ['05-1898', ' 1.22'], ['01-1678', ' 1.34'], ['04-1577', ' 1.38'], ['03-1678', ' 1.54'], ['06-1966', ' 1.66']]
```

Sorting by value works fine, but the dates are, of course, read as strings and thus not sorted correctly. So the data in this column will first need to be converted to YYYY-MM format for this script to work. But maybe this is something to work with...

Comment: PS: If you let Python count the number of rows for you, you can also get the largest numbers in each column by calling the last six items accordingly.